# How can I paste data from array to specific range (row)

Tags: excel, vba, range

I´m beginner in EXCEL VBA and I would like to create my own trading diary for stock trading.

1. I created a simple calculator that calculates values ​​for entering to trade. After clicking on "SEND TO ACTIVE>", the values ​​are saved in the created array and are to be saved on the first free row in the "Active >>>" table. Currently my data is written only from line B21, however I need to save it from line B5. The table is limited to 13 records (that's enough). I add the "Close Price" cell manually after the end of the trade.[Screenshot1 - paste data from array to specific row - Active table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TF9s.jpg)
2. After finishing the trade, I need to move the row to the "History Of Trade >>>" table. After clicking on the "> SEND TO HISTORY" button, I need to delete the data in the current row and move it to the new row in the table below. I need the latest data to always be at the top - so create a new row and move all already saved data one row lower.[Screenshot2 - paste data from array to specific row - History table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvHK5.jpg)

I also need to automatically calculate the following values ​​in the line:

```
Date Close = add Current Date

Day = Date Close - Date Open

Profit / Loss = Close Price - Entry Price

Result = if Profit / Loss is a positive number so write "WIN" otherwise write "LOSE".
```

I will be very happy if you can advise me on at least some part. Thank you very much!

Here is my code to insert the data from the array into a new line:

```
Sub Save_calc()
'Define an array to contain your data
Dim DatAa() As Variant
ReDim DatAa(1 To 1, 1 To 12)

'Define the sheet you want to work on
Dim wS As Worksheet
Set wS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'Fill the data array
DatAa(1, 1) = "=TODAY()"
DatAa(1, 2) = "///"
DatAa(1, 3) = "///"
DatAa(1, 4) = wS.Range("Q14").Value
DatAa(1, 5) = "Stock"
DatAa(1, 6) = wS.Range("Q7").Value
DatAa(1, 7) = wS.Range("S9").Value
DatAa(1, 8) = wS.Range("Q9").Value
DatAa(1, 9) = ""
DatAa(1, 10) = wS.Range("Q10").Value
DatAa(1, 11) = wS.Range("Q11").Value
DatAa(1, 12) = wS.Range("S7").Value

'Find the first available row
Dim NextRow As Long
NextRow = wS.Range("B" & wS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'Print your data in there
wS.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(UBound(DatAa, 1), UBound(DatAa, 2)).Value = DatAa

End Sub
```

Comment: Your images are quite confusing. If you could post an image of before and another of after the 'paste', this might become clear.

Comment: OK, I understand, thanks. Tomorrow I will send image before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Save_calc()
    'Define an array to contain your data
    Dim DatAa() As Variant
    ReDim DatAa(1 To 1, 1 To 12)
    
    'Define the sheet you want to work on
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    'Fill the data array
    DatAa(1, 1) = Date
    DatAa(1, 2) = "///"
    DatAa(1, 3) = "///"
    DatAa(1, 4) = wS.Range("Q14").Value
    DatAa(1, 5) = "Stock"
    DatAa(1, 6) = wS.Range("Q7").Value
    DatAa(1, 7) = wS.Range("S9").Value
    DatAa(1, 8) = wS.Range("Q9").Value
    DatAa(1, 9) = ""
    DatAa(1, 10) = wS.Range("Q10").Value
    DatAa(1, 11) = wS.Range("Q11").Value
    DatAa(1, 12) = wS.Range("S7").Value
    
    'Find the first available row
    Dim NextRow As Long
    NextRow = wS.Range("B18").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim iAnswer As Integer
    If wS.Range("b5") = "" Then
    Else
        If NextRow = 5 Then
            iAnswer = MsgBox("Data has been exceeded. Would you like to erase existing data?", vbYesNo)
            If iAnswer = vbYes Then
                wS.Range("b5", "m17") = Empty
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'Print your data in there
    wS.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(UBound(DatAa, 1), UBound(DatAa, 2)).Value = DatAa

End Sub
Sub SendToHistory()
    'Define an array to contain your data
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim vHistory As Variant
    Dim rngHistory As Range
    
    'Define the sheet you want to work on
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    
    
    'Find the first available row
    Dim NextRow As Long
    NextRow = wS.Range("B18").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If NextRow = 4 Then
        If wS.Range("b5") <> "" Then
            NextRow = 17
        Else
            MsgBox "No Data!!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
        
    
    Dim Target As Range
    
    Set Target = wS.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(1, 12)
    vData = Target
    Target = Empty
    'date closed current date
    vData(1, 2) = Date
    vData(1, 3) = vData(1, 2) - vData(1, 2) 'day
    vData(1, 10) = vData(1, 9) - vData(1, 8) 'Profit/Loss
    If vData(1, 10) >= 0 Then
        vData(1, 11) = "WIN"
    Else
        vData(1, 11) = "LOSE"
    End If
    vData(1, 12) = Empty 'Note
    
    
    NextRow = wS.Range("B" & wS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If NextRow > 18 Then
        Set rngHistory = wS.Range("B19", "M" & NextRow)
        
        vHistory = rngHistory
        rngHistory = Empty
    End If
    
    wS.Range("B19").Resize(UBound(vData, 1), UBound(vData, 2)).Value = vData
    If IsArray(vHistory) Then
        NextRow = wS.Range("B" & wS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wS.Range("B" & NextRow).Resize(UBound(vHistory, 1), UBound(vHistory, 2)) = vHistory
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The first part - (SEND TO ACTIVE>) works absolutely great! Thank you so much for your help!

The second part - after clicking on the button (SEND TO HISTORY>) appears Run-time error ´13´ Type mismatch referring to the code line: wS.Range ("B19"). Resize (UBound (DatAa, 1), UBound (DatAa , 2)) .Value = DatAa
At the same time, the data from lines B5, B18, and B19 disappears.
If I click the (SEND TO HISTORY>) button again, line B4 will also disappear:(

Comment: Required function:
After clicking the (SEND TO HISTORY>) button, the data in row 5 in range B5 to M5 are extracted (CTRL + X) and inserted into row 19 in range B19 to M19. Each subsequent click on the button (SEND TO HISTORY>) will have the same function.
And all "historical records" are automatically shifted 1 line down into the line 20.

Is it possible?

Comment: Last question, how can I calculate these 4 automatically functions?

Cell C19 => "Date Close" = add Current Date

Cell D19 => "Day" = Date Close - Date Open

Cell K19 => "Profit/Loss" = Close Price - Entry Price

Cell L19 => "Result" = if Profit/Loss is a positive number so write "WIN" otherwise write "LOSE".